# How to check if geopoint type set to null in elasticsearch using mvel?

Tags: elasticsearch, mvel

How do i check if a geopoint value is set to null (for custom scoring using mvel)? Should the value be '' or null? And if so how do i check if the value is '' or null?
So my document structure is like this

```
   document 1
   {
   "id" : 100
   "location" : null
   }

   document 2
   {
   "id" : 200
   "location" : "80.230122,80.97629"
   }
```

Here location is of type geopoint in the mapping.
When scoring using custom scripts I would like to do something like:

```
distance=doc['location'].distanceInKm(latitude, longitude)
```

where I pass latitude and longitude. How do I check for document with id 100 which has the null value for location, and make the distance calculated zero? .empty and .Isempty() doesn't seem to be working.

Note: for document id 100 location is null and not string null. Also I'm using MVEL plugin version 1.5 with ES version 1.5

Comment: can you elaborate your question, posting some code will help others

Comment: So a check like `doc['location'].empty` works